# Intermittent AJAX errors on live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this form processed through AJAX. All through my testing on my local server,  I never for once experienced this problem until I uploaded files to my live server.

When form is filled like for example 10 times, 3 times out of 10, it would go through without throwing an error. But the remain 7 times, it throws this error with some variations to the responses.

In those 7 times, I get errors like:

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST https://www.example.com/ApplicationCheck.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   application.js:62
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
y.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
------------------
```

And the below response:

```
jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: POST "https://www.example.com/ApplicationCheck.php".
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   application.js:62
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
y.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
---------------------------------------------
```

Now, here is the part of the "application.js" that references line 62

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#error").hide();
  $("#loader").hide();

  $('#ApplicationCheckerForm').submit(function(event) {
    $("#error").hide();

    var formData = {
      'ResidentCountry': $('select#ResidentCountry').val(),
      'Email': $('input[name=Email]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../greenwich/ApplicationCheck',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#error").hide();
        $("#loader").show();
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("input[type=text]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("input[type=password]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      },
      encode: true
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      if (!data.success) {
        if (data.errors.Error) {
          $("#ResidentCountry").val("");
          $("#Email").val("");
          $("#checkbox").prop("checked", false);
          $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("input[type=text]").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("input[type=password]").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("select").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#error").show(function() {
            $('#error').html('' + data.errors.Error + '');
          });
          $("#loader").fadeOut(200);
        }
      } else {
        $("#loader").hide();
        $("#error2").hide();
        $("#error3").hide();
        $("#loader2").hide();
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("input[type=text]").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("input[type=password]").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("select").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#StartApplicationModal").modal({
          backdrop: 'static',
          keyboard: false
        });
        $('#StartApplicationModal').modal('show');
      }
    }).fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Having posted the above, I am at a loss what causes the above errors. The errors I get again are:

1. jquery.min.js:2 POST https://www.example.com/ApplicationCheck.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
2. jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: POST "https://www.example.com/ApplicationCheck.php".
3. A few times, I get ERR SSL. (I can reproduce this error at the moment to post exact)

I would be so happy if someone would be kind enough to guide me through this, show me a possible solution or point to me where I might be going wrong. Thanks!

Here is my server PHP.ini config and limitations:

```html
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 90
   php_value max_input_time 90
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 100M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Comment: If you're getting intermittent problems on your live server but it works fine locally then it's likely to be a server-side issue to do with configuration or rate-limiting. I'd suggest checking your logs.

Comment: so what is the error codes from the server 5xx? I doubt the issue is with the browser.

Comment: I have edited my question to include my server's php.ini configs and limitations. Any suggestions where I am getting it wrong? It was so smooth on XAMPP.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have searched my server error logs and there is nothing in there. I really need a guide on where to center my focus on towards resolving this. At the moment, I am not finding answers. Any help will be appreciated.